# making ISBN-10 identifier in python

Tags: python-3.8

This question is from codewars.

```
ISBN-10 identifiers are ten digits long. The first nine characters are digits 0-9. The last 
digit can be 0-9 or X, to indicate a value of 10.

An ISBN-10 number is valid if the sum of the digits multiplied by their position modulo 11 
equals zero.
```

My code

```
def valid_ISBN10(isbn):
    sum = 0
    
    if len(isbn) == 10 and isbn[0:8].isdigit():
        for i,x in enumerate(isbn):
            if x != 'X':
                sum += (int(x))*(i+1)
            if isbn[9] == 'X':
                sum += 100
        return sum % 11 == 0
    else:return False
```

When I attempt its shows 105 passed,4 failed.when again attempted shows 103 passed,6 failed.
I don't understand why.But I think I didn't mention all rules in my code.Can you please tell where I have done mistake.should I replace anything in it?

Comment: Can you share a few ISBN you tried your function on?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a actually wrong. Here is a valid ISBN10 code: `048665088X`. Your function returns that it is `False`.

The following function return `True` and also makes sure you don't have to remove the dashes that exist in many ISBN10 codes

```
def valid_ISBN10(isbn):
    remove_dashes = isbn.replace('-', '')
    if (len(remove_dashes) != 10):
        return False

    result = 0
    for index, multiplier in enumerate(reversed(range(1, 11))):
        char = remove_dashes[index]
        if char.isalpha() and char == 'X' and not index == 9:
            return False
        elif char.isalpha() and not char == 'X':
            return False
        elif char.isalpha() and char == 'X' and index == 9:
            result = result + (10 * multiplier)
        else:
            result = result + (int(char) * multiplier)
    if not (result % 11):
        return True
    return False
```